# GenServer search key-value pairs from database [Elixir]

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to search for key-value pairs that I have stored in my genserver. There is something wrong with my syntax for how I'm passing a map into my handle_call function I think.

This is my search function and handle callback function:

```rb
def search(bucket, key_value_list) do
  Enum.map(key_value_list, fn {key, value} ->
    GenServer.call(bucket, {:search, key_value_list})
  end)
end 

def handle_call({:search, key_value_list}, from, state) do
  {:noreply, Map.get(key_value_list)}
end
```

Error message:

```rb
{:ok, orders} = Server.Database.search(database, [{"order_details", "000147760"}])
16:52:07.960 [error] GenServer #PID<0.320.0> terminating
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Map.get/1 is undefined or private
    (elixir) Map.get([{"order_details", "000147760"}])
    (tuto_kbrw_stack) lib/server/database.ex:45: Server.Database.handle_call/3
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:661: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:690: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I'm brand new to Elixir so appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read documentation of [`Map.get/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#get/3), you can notice that it takes 3 arguments. Assuming that you stored the state as a map correctly, then you need to change:

```
def handle_call({:search, key_value_list}, from, state) do
  {:reply, Map.get(state, key_value_list), state}
end
```

Edit: On further inspection it seems you have multiple errors, so I'll post on how your genserver should look:

```
defmodule GenserverExample do
  use GenServer

  def init(map) when is_map(map) do
    {:ok, map}
  end

  def search(bucket, search_list) when is_list(search_list) do
    GenServer.call(bucket, {:search, search_list})
  end

  def handle_call({:search, search_list}, _from, state) do
    results = Enum.map(search_list, fn search_element -> Map.get(state, search_element) end)
    {:reply, results, state}
  end
end
```

Comment: also you can notice that I changed the format of the message, in cases where you expect a reply, you need to use the `:reply` atom with the reply and the new state.

Comment: [`Map.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html#take/2) → `results = Map.take(state, search_list)` :)